# Mysql JOIN do i need FOREACH?

Tags: php, mysql

This is my current code:

```
<?php
$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user     = "r0rypu115";
$mysql_password = "VSVMj9Py";
$mysql_database = "r0rypu115";
$bd             = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Oops some thing went wrong");// we are now connected to database

//$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_products ORDER BY bankIds"); // selecting data through mysql_query()
$result = mysql_query("
SELECT a.id,a.bankIds,a.sku,a.productTitle,a.productTitle,a.prodDesc,a.seed,a.productImg,a.characteristics,b.bankTitle,c.productID,c.bundleQty,c.bundlePrice,c.bundleSKU,c.seed
FROM tbl_products a 
JOIN tbl_seedBank b 
ON a.bankIds=b.id
JOIN tbl_bundles c
ON a.id=c.productID
ORDER BY bankTitle");

echo'<table border=1px>';
echo'<th>Collection</th><th>Vendor</th><th>Product</th><th>SKU</th><th>Description</th><th>Charactersitics</th><th>Bundles</th><th>Reg/Fem</th><th>Image</th>';

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo'<tr>';
echo'<td>'.strip_tags($data['bankTitle']).'</td>
        <td>'.strip_tags($data['bankTitle']).'</td>
        <td>'.strip_tags($data['productTitle']).'</td>
        <td>'.strip_tags($data['sku']).'</td>
        <td><h3>Description</h3>'.$data['prodDesc'].'</td>
        <td><h3>characteristics</h3>'.$data['characteristics'].'</td>
        <td>'.$data['bundleQty'].'<br/>'.$data['seed'].'<br/>'.$data['bundlePrice'].'<br/>'.$data['bundleSKU'].'</td>
        <td>'.strip_tags($data['seed']).'</td>
        <td><image width="150px" height="150px" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0709/2915/files/'.$data['productImg'].'"/></td>';
echo'</tr>';

}
echo'</table>';
?>
```

Now all works good, however!
The returned vale of this line of code:

```
<td>'.$data['bundleQty'].'<br/>'.$data['seed'].'<br/>'.$data['bundlePrice'].'<br/>'.$data['bundleSKU'].'</td>
```

Returns results on another row in the table, yes it grabs all the info need but i would like to get the results into the same row, just a new column for each...

Bundles are tied to product id's and there are various bundles per product...
Like i say, ive got the info coming back correctly, but id like to have the bundles on the same row as the product and not create a new row for each and every bundle.

Kindest regards and thanks for looking at my issue.
~~ Rory

> Been searching for hours and cant seem to find an answer anywhere :( i really could do with some PHP FOR DUMMIES help :(

Comment: Are you saying each productDesc is repeated for every bundleQty, and that you'd like productDesc to be shown once, then list all its bundles as a kind of sub-list?

Comment: Pretty much yes, im structuring my data in a table and would like to display ALL bundles from a specific product within the BUNDLES column.
Hope that makes sense lol

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to set a var which remembers the last product, then if this product is the same as the last product, then do not echo out the product, but add, say a new row with just a bundle.

The solution in pseudocode will be something akin to this:

```
$last_product = ''; // before the loop starts

foreach( of your rows) { // as you have it

if( $last_product !== this product) {

// reset the temp variable
$last_product = this product;

//now echo out the bank, product etc

} // end of the conditional check

// echo out the rows of the bundle anyway, as you have it now

} // end of the loop
```

I'd get this working without the tables first - with a minimum of data being output. It wont be pretty but will have the data doing what you want, then, gradually add in table tr td etc, otherwise you risk ending up confusing yourself with data hidden in badly formed html, looking at source code and so on.

Comment: yup, thats just confused the hell out me lol
Could you possibly tie it into my code so i can kind of understand your meaning ?  :)

Comment: You can see my current results here:
http://420cannabisseeds.co.uk/database/dev.php

And the tables here:
http://420cannabisseeds.co.uk/database/query.php